# table has no column named image

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've wrote a code to save database with text and image. After add an image I've get an error and my notes don't display in my list view.

> 2020-02-27 00:17:54.881 18498-18498/com.example.myapplication
>   E/SQLiteLog: (1) table notestables has no column named image
>
> 2020-02-27 00:17:54.881 18498-18498/com.example.myapplication
>   E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting image=[B@86bec14 phone=test
>   date=26-2-2020 client=test time=12:17 title=test content=test age=test
>        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table notestables has no column named image (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT
>   INTO notestables(image,phone,date,client,time,title,content,age)
>   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

That's how I converted bitmap to byte in AddNote class

```
public static byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        return byteArray;
    }
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.save_note){

            Note note = new Note(noteTitle.getText().toString(),
                    noteContent.getText().toString(),
                    notePhone.getText().toString(),
                    noteClient.getText().toString(),
                    noteAge.getText().toString(),
                    todaysDate,currentTime,
                    imageViewToByte(noteImage));



            NoteDatabase db = new NoteDatabase(this);
            db.addNote(note);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            goToMain();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

and that's my "ShowNote" class

```
   contentDetails = findViewById(R.id.contentOfNote);
            titleDetails = findViewById(R.id.titleOfNote);
            phoneDetails = findViewById(R.id.phoneOfNote);
            clientDetails = findViewById(R.id.clientOfNote);
            ageDetails = findViewById(R.id.ageOfNote);
            imageDetails = findViewById(R.id.imageOfNote);

 contentDetails.setText(note.getContent());
            titleDetails.setText(note.getTitle());
            phoneDetails.setText(note.getPhone());
            clientDetails.setText(note.getClient());
            ageDetails.setText(note.getAge());
            imageDetails.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

I didnt reconvert byte to bitmap here, maybe that why it doesn't work ?

Please help